# Html - Javascript: Mysql doesnt saving data in database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, database

i just have a register button in my html as follows, which calls the `register()` function from the `insert.js` file. When i run alone the `insert.js` script it writes data to my database. The problem is that when i combine it(the js script) with this html code, it writes nothing. What im doing wrong?

```
<form method="post">
 <div class="inputs">
 <div class="input">
 <input placeholder="Email" name="email"  type="text">
 <img src="img/mail.svg">
 </div>
 <div class="input">
 <input placeholder="username" name="username" type="text">
 <img src="img/user.svg"> 
 </div>
 <div class="input">
 <input placeholder="password" name = "password" type="password">
 <img src="img/pass.svg">
 </div>
 </div>
 <button onclick="register()" >Register</button>
</form>
<script src="insert.js"></script>
```

my insert.js file

```
function register()
{
    var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "assessment"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('james', 'bond007')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");

  });
});
}
```

Comment: it is nodejs module. you  not be able to run it in browser

Comment: @Daviti you are right. But, is there a way to combine them?

Comment: yes you can implement this on backend with [expressjs framework](https://expressjs.com/). for front end implementation you can use template engine like ejs or jade. maybe express default template engine is jade

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that js file its node which is back-end, installed on a server and the HTML it's front-end which runs on the user machine, that js it's fine but should be accessible for the HTML, the front, whoever uses your application, through an endpoint which you can do on node, but I could be wrong if you are using some kind of framework...

Comment: ohh thats true. But is there a way to combine those 2 ? i mean my front end with backend?

Comment: Also php is a backend language, but its possible to combine those 2!. Im confused now

Comment: Of course but the back-end has to expose that functionality to the front, that's why I recommended a node endpoint https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb
And from the front end make an XHR request, asking to the server to execute that back-end functionality.
What you're referring to with PHP it's Server Side Rendering, that means that the back-end can apply some logic to what the front it's gonna show, but that front it's requested to the back-end then it runs on the user machine, i.e in their browser